# What would cause these spikes on a nuclear radiation graph?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, gamma-rays

I recorded the level of radiation in my apartment using a GMC-320+ overnight (roughly 8 hours) and awoke to find the graph below.  Interestingly, both of the spikes took place at 55 minutes past the hour.  What might have caused these spikes?  I live across the street from both a Hospital and a Linear Accelerator, if that might help explain anything.

[image: GMC-320+ Readings Over 8 Hours]

Comment: Keep measuring. It would be nice to know the distribution of intervals between counts, that could also say something about the cause. Try to get a gamma spectrometer.

Comment: what is a GMC-320+?  I assume the x-axis corresponds to energy or pulse height someway?

Answer (score 1):

If you're really interested, take these measurements everyday over a month a you could notice a pattern. In any case, radiation spikes can come from a variety of things. K-40 reflecting off of walls, background cosmic, fancy "glow-in-the-dark" fluorescent objects that fluoresce on detecting gammas or alphas, lamps, bulbs, etc. Those spikes, however, can be very well strong x-rays (yousaid you were close to a hospital, that might explain a lot, or even if you're close to an airport, but you'd have to be really close). If you see a pattern, it could be from the hospital or some system. See if you can change the location of your counter. Take it to the living room, bathroom, set it beside a block of lead (if you have one) or next to concrete.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question